# Is there a way to map the listArray function to a tuple of lists?

Tags: arrays, list, algorithm, haskell

Is it possible to apply the function `listArray`, of type `Ix a => (a,a) -> [b] -> Array a b` to a tuple of lists?

For example, `listArray (1,5) [4,5,6,7,8]` will output `array (1,5) [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(4,7),(5,8)]`

I tried the following, (all lists have length 3):

`(xs, ys, zs) = map listArray (1, 3) ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])`

However, this implementation does not work and I am hoping if anyone would provide their insights to this problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot map over the elements of a tuple. But you can map over a list.

```
[xs, ys, zs] = map (listArray (1,10)) [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

Of course you need to provide ten elements in each sublist!

Comment: Thank you! Yep sorry that was a mistake on my part, I made up numbers for my question and forgot to change that part!